# Scientific stance on 'life from non-life, naturally'?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, life, materialism, philosophy-of-biology

As far as I'm aware, almost everyone (from Dawkins to Lennox to Hovind) agrees that at some point in the past there was no life in our universe, and currently there is.  Therefore life somehow arose in an environment of non-life.

**What does current mainstream science think about the statement "life arose from non-life *by purely material processes*"?**  What I mean is, is that statement an a priori assumption, a potential conclusion, an actual conclusion, a wish, a research program guideline, ...?

- #1 We assume a priori it is true, because science *assumes* materialism: one cannot really be a scientist unless one is a materialist, 'real scientists don't believe in God.'
- #2 We assume a priori it is true, because science is *about* material processes: the statement might be very well be false, but in that case it falls out side the realm of science and should be studied under the heading of religion of some such: 'you can't talk about miracles here.'
- #3 We make no assumption either way, but draw conclusions based on the evidence: for example, can we find evidence of natural processes that have led to life, processes powerful enough to overcome the natural processes that we know are hostile to life?
- #4 We want it to be true, because many scientists happen to be materialists, and therefore we discard, ignore, or even censor any evidence against this statement; 'it must have happened naturally, anything else is religious nonsense.'
- *(other)*

(Options numbered for easy of reference.)

---

The reason I'm asking, is that current origin-of-life research seems to be mostly involved in storytelling, or at least that is what it feels like to me: 'It must have happened; what if this behavior in this lab experiment helped to naturally bring about one piece of the puzzle, millions of years ago?'  And it seems to ignore natural processes continuously trying to break down life, and again to me it feels like: 'It must have happened, so *some* process was strong enough to break through any opposition, so we don't have to look at that evidence.'

But I might be mistaken there.  I'm not a biologist, not even a scientist, and not even a philosopher. :-)

---

(Note that I'm avoiding the term 'abiogenesis' here because some, like Wikipedia [1], *define* this to be a natural process; while all dictionary definitions I could find, e.g. [2], [3], just define it as 'life arising from non-life'; and some even say it is hypothetical, e.g. [3], [4].  Also, many dictionary definitions, like [3] and [4], equate it to spontaneous generation, while at least one encyclopedia takes care to distinguish the two [5].

Note also that I'm not sure that a precise definition of 'life' would be relevant here.  You can read 'DNA-based life' instead if you want, or 'the whole process that we all recognize as stopping whenever a human being or animal dies'.

*Update.* What I mean with 'mainstream science' is just scientists, I guess mainly biologists, and what most of them they say and do in their work and papers and conferences.  I don't mean any theoretical ideal of what science should be in the eyes of scientists, philosophers, judges, lawmakers, or anyone else.)

---

[1] Abiogenesis, https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Abiogenesis&oldid=1100445628 (last visited Aug. 11, 2022).

[2] https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abiogenesis

[3] https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=abiogenesis

[4] http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=abiogenesis

[5] https://www.britannica.com/science/abiogenesis

Comment: I'm not sure the title of this question is correct.  As I said, I'm not a philosopher.  Improvement suggestions welcome.

Comment: Any historical reconstruction is "storytelling", we develop speculative theories consistent with natural laws and the known outcome and then try to find their experimental/observational confirmations or refutations. It worked the same way with the Big Bang theory. That X happened through natural processes is a methodological assumption of science for any X too, it is a precondition of scientific study. The prevailing current theory of abiogenesis seems to be the [RNA-peptide world](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-022-04676-3), and it is pretty detailed for a mere "story".

Comment: I would suggest a better title would be "Scientific stance on origin of life". Epistemology is about how knowledge is acquired.

Comment: @Conifold Interesting that you say, "That X \[life from non-life\] happened through natural processes \[...\] is a precondition of scientific study." So you are choosing (what I just now called) option #2? And is that the mainstream science opinion / stance? (If so, my follow-up question is, I think: What happens if there is evidence making it very unlikely that X occurred naturally? A peer-reviewed paper saying, 'We can all stop studying X now because God must have done it'?)

Comment: This is too small for an answer, but I find there is marked variety in what definitions of "life" are used.  Indeed, I find many people actually use different shades of the word in different discussions and contexts.

Comment: I find it more useful to think of it as life coming from proto-life, and proto-life coming from non-life. Then you get a spectrum of less lifelike to more lifelike instead of a "giant leap". Is a virus alive? Depends on your definition. It occupies an in between state between being fully alive and fully non-alive.

Comment: Science doesn't assume materialism, nor is it necessarily about material processes. If ghosts were real, and we could empirically detect their existence and study what they do or how they work, then this study would be scientific, but not materialist. Materialism is a *conclusion* of science, not a premise: everything science studies can be explained well by the theory that things are made up of material components such as particles or waves. The success of this materialist theory in explaining and predicting things gives it credence.

Comment: You need to define "mainstream science". To some people it means stuff proved and tested and peer-reviewed, to some it means stuff that disagrees with what I just saw on YouTube.

Comment: @causative If ghosts are real then they would just be a "new form of mater", and materialism would be preserved.

Comment: @StevenGubkin In that last comment, you seem to assume 'everything real is material', which would imply that e.g. the God of the Bible is not real, I think?

Comment: @MarnixKloosterReinstateMonica For me "material" and "real" are synonymous.  My definition is that something is real we can somehow get it to move a dial.  If the tales in the Bible are true, then God can make dials move.  In which case, he is real/material.

Comment: One important clarification: if the first life on Earth arrived from outer space, would you consider that falsification of the hypothesis, or another way for life to appear on Earth through natural processes?

Comment: You might find the [Origins of Life](https://www.complexityexplorer.org/courses/155-origins-of-life) course interesting; it surveys the current state of research, and tries to resolve the issues between the metabolism first school and the reproduction first..

Comment: Santa Fe Institute are running a free course on the [Origins of Life](https://www.complexityexplorer.org/courses/155-origins-of-life), which covers current research, and compares "metabolism first" and "reproduction first" hypotheses.

Comment: A big thank-you to everyone taking part in this conversation! Note that I will keep away from the term 'abiogenesis' precisely because I don't know whether the 'it happened naturally' is part of its definition or not, for any of us.  (And it seems to me that if abiogenesis is _just_ 'life arose in an environment when there was none before', then I'm not sure what we are talking about: As I start out my question, doesn't basically _everyone_ agree on that? Or am I missing a distinction here?)

Comment: Scientists [that I have worked with] assume that supernatural beings do not intervene in their field of study: a scientist who believes G-d sent smallpox to punish sinners is unlikely to invent vaccines. Moreover the reward structure in science is set up to benefit those who solve problems, not those who think they are too hard. So any specialization selects people who believe they have a chance of success.
BTW, some researchers are moving towards a gradualist position on Origins, e.g. [The Grayness of the Origin of Life](https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1729/11/6/498)

Comment: 'real scientists don't believe in God.' This is simply not true. All that is required is to avoid assuming the explanation for their own field of study is supernatural. Because, after all, looking for a natural explanation is a scientists job, and therefore assuming a supernatural one is just giving up on their own job.

Answer (score 25):

First, please refrain from terms like 'mainstream science'. There is science, based on reproducible processes with empirical evidence, and there are other human practices. Some science may be known better but the standard is set.

Abiogenesis is a *hypothesis* of science. This hypothesis is scientific since it is based on available evidence and testable with scientific methods eventually. And it is still only a hypothesis since nobody was able to show that all processes needed for abiogenesis are possible in a natural environment and how yet. If all this were added (experimental evidence and, more importantly, explanations and mechanisms with predictive power for every step and process needed), it would become a fully fledged scientific *theory*.

Hypotheses are effectively *guidelines* for scientific practice: They provide a frame of what to look for in terms of further empirical evidence. This scientific inquiry may solicit evidence *against* the hypothesis, in which case it has to be discarded or modified.

Incidentally, I am not aware of any other *scientific* hypothesis about the genesis of life. Since for that, we would need to suggest a different reproducible, empirically accessible process and at least some existing evidence, processes, and explanations that support the hypothesis. A claim isn't a *scientific* hypothesis just because it touches the same subject as one.

#### Could divine genesis become a scientific theory?

Let's play this through...

Let's assume a group works on scientific abiogenesis and conducts a long series of experiments, trying all possibilities they can imagine. Ultimately, they experience divine revelation and God basically tells them "Well, you've tried so hard but there's nothing to be found since I did it!".

Could they publish that in a scientific, peer-reviewed journal? Never say never but highly unlikely. It lacks a crucial element of scientific practice: **reproducibility**.

Now, let's assume a different group conducts the same series of experiments either by chance or because God said they'll tell equally dedicated people the same and the same thing happens. Would this change things? Oh hell (sic!) yeah!

It means there is a reproducible process with the same verifiable, empirical outcome. Also, we would probably see a stark rise in the number of scientific validations because many people will want to undergo that process. Science wins, always!

We do not have the slightest reason in the form of existing reproducible evidence to assume that hypothesis though. And thus, it is unscientific.

Comment: Technically, [panspermia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panspermia) is a scientific, physicalist-friendly hypothesis that might be favored by an exobiologist unconvinced by abiogenesis, but I doubt it has much political support.

Comment: @JD That does not explain the origin of life as such (as opposed to life on earth), which is the real question as I take it.

Comment: I don't like how this is framed as "science vs religion". If your statement "Science wins, always" was meant as in "against religion", then, humbly, you may want to question and reevaluate your own understanding of religion.

Comment: @csstudent1418 Winning doesn't always require conflict; it just requires success. As I read it, it's science v.s. not-science; just because some of that not-science happens to be part of some religions doesn't mean this answer is pitting science and religion against each other.

Comment: @csstudent1418 For once, the smiley is part of the assertion and designates it as not to be taken too serious. Also, this is meant as  "Science profits because of its consistent success as a methodology." It won't take away belief from faithful people. There isn't any real competition as they are different domains of human practice. And I am clearly for not mingling statements from science and religion on the same subjects *either way*. Religion should not act as if it offered an alternative science, science should not try to say anything on religious questions. Truth is domain-bound anyways.

Comment: "There isn't any real competition" - exactly that's just what I wish more non-religious folks acknowledged. "science should not try to say anything on religious questions." - agreed, which (side-note) includes anything related to morals. Wish more nonbelievers acknowledged that as well. Thank you.

Comment: Ah! Point conceded.

Comment: @csstudent1418 I beg to differ. Science can say something on morals with the very same entitlement as religion can. If it has something substantial to say, for example if natural sciences found that certain practices solicit a certain neural reaction pattern that is linked to extremely negative feelings across cultures and the very same extremely negative feeling patterns highly correlate with moral practices, why should **any** religion be in the position to claim that they and noone else would be allowed to say that science had 'no right' to say this about morals? There's no special right.

Comment: Age-old debate, you are simply applying utilitarianism. That is philosophy, not materialist science. To a true materialist - you know one who doesn't borrow religious terms like _morality_ under the disguise of merely doing science - negative feelings do not matter in any regard because they are nothing but chemistry. Just like religions can't arbitrarily redefine gravity, science can't (re-)define morals. Morals have no part in the scientific framework, there is no equation or scientific hypothesis that includes morals as a factor.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Science cannot conclude whether or not the presence of such neural reactions is right or wrong. That’s the crux. It is not rare to find moral systems whereby suffering is right and good to be endured in life for the sake of others or an afterlife. Science cannot prove it is morally wrong for suffering to occur because it cannot, by itself, prove anything is morally wrong.

Comment: @JustSomeOldMan My point is that *everyone* has a say in morals, regardless of their background. Moral discourse by no means is exclusively religious. Also, I chose my example so that science does not have to say anything on right or wrong in the sense of value judgements. In the example, they only say *what* people feel as wrong and *that* this correlates with moral labelling.

Comment: @csstudent1418 See my previous comment. We don't have to induce another *Werturteilsstreit* in order to allow science a word on moral reality.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking _Everyone_ has a say in morals only in so far as their moral judgement is derived from either an overarching philosophy/ideology (e.g. religion, utilitarianism, ...) *or* their own conscience, any of which _may or may not_ invoke some _metrics_ (e.g. "pain-level") provided by science. But the moral value judgement still comes from said philosophy/ideology, not from science itself - as you seem to agree with. Your whole argument is missing the complete layer of philosophy/ideology between science and morals. It stands that science, by definition, is moral-less.

Comment: @csstudent1418 You might want to look up the term *Werturteilsstreit*. It is highly debatable, and still discussed, whether this is the case.

Comment: Re: “[Abiogenesis] is still only a hypothesis since nobody was able to show that all processes needed for abiogenesis are possible in a natural environment and how yet,” isn’t abiogenesis _always_ going to be a hypothesis? Hypotheses never stop being hypotheses, there is no “graduation” to any other “higher” form of science. It will never become a “law,” for example, though we may discover laws relating to it, because laws and hypotheses are separate things.

Comment: @KRyan Yes and no. In a sense, you are correct. I would say that established hypotheses that are fully empirically validated are the current scientific *theory*, though. Also, hypotheses are commonly understood in the sense described: working hypotheses that guide the direction of experimental study as they pose definite *questions* that are to be answered.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Derp, of course; I got mixed up.

Comment: You can easily imagine scientific evidence for divine creation. Example: if bones naturally all develop with a watermark, "This trial version of GodSoft will expire in 17 eons." That no such evidence has been found does not make it "unscientific", it just suggests that there are better explanations.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking (Not sure I'm stating this clearly, please bear with me. Am I going wrong in my reasoning here?) If 'life from non-life naturally' is a hypothesis, then it is falsifiable. Then if it is proven false, and given that we all agree that there is now life where once there was none, then the _scientific_ peer-reviewed consensus conclusion would be 'life arose by non-material means', by something that is in some sense immaterial, supernatural, 'outside' of the universe, or however you want to call it.

Comment: I like this distinction: "A proposition that has not been proved but is believed to be true is known as a conjecture, or a hypothesis if frequently used as an assumption for further mathematical work."

Comment: @MarnixKloosterReinstateMonica: I would argue life from non-life on Earth is a conjecture (vs eg pantheism, panspermia). *Specific mechanisms* for specific steps can form falsifiable hypotheses eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Urey_experiment There are other specific ideas like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_world White-smoker hydrothermal vents are widely considered a very plausible candidate now, & chemistry there can be investigated. Cellular life started less than 0.1 billion after the formation of Earth's crust, imposing strict criteria on time/statistics

Comment: @MarnixKloosterReinstateMonica Correct in  theory. We have no way to prove a general negative though (life did **not** emerge from material causes). Thus, the heuristically more solid assertion would be "We ruled out all mechanisms we know at the moment, so there has to be an unknown process." Mind, science doesn't care about whether a mechanism is materialistic or not, it just has to be empirically accessible, reproducible, and reliable, ie. consistently produce the same results. Assuming we ruled out all material causes would assume omniscience, which we are not capable of.

Comment: @MarnixKloosterReinstateMonica: What exactly do people mean by god? Even Christians can't agree among themselves. How can something non-physical, influence the physical, surely that would make it physical - Elizabeth of Bohemia's criticism of Descartes. The problem is: 'God Is Not A Good Theory' (talk by Sean Carroll) https://youtu.be/ew_cNONhhKI

Comment: How could abiogenesis ever be testable with the scientific method? We can't go back to a time before life and observe it coming it existence! Even if it was observed to happen in the future it wouldn't prove it was the origin of life now.

Comment: @curiousdannii Abiogenesis means nothing more than *the becoming of life from non-living matter*, literally. If science can show that and how this works, it validated the hypothesis proper. Also, it makes it *highly probable* as a historical fact. There are no historical facts that are scientifically testable beyond that. Science is all about the explanation that fits best with our empirical findings.

Comment: @MarnixKloosterReinstateMonica - I think "life arose from non-life by natural processes" needs to be better defined. Before we can even answer the question of whether it's a falsifiable hypothesis, we need to know what's being talked about. What are "natural processes?" What would be an example of a non-natural process? What makes a non-natural process non-natural?

Answer (score 7):

This topic has been beaten to death in many many forums. A quick net search on abiogenesis would yield a very large amount of hits. There is even a web site with a  FAQ on it at http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/abioprob/  This web site grew out of the old usenet newsgroup talk.origins. Caveat: That website is dedicated to the confrontation between scientists and creationists, so you will see a certain stance quite heavily evidenced.

In any meaningful interpretation of the term, life is a "purely material process." We don't see life without matter. When we manipulate the matter life is made of, the life responds as material stuff. "If you prick us, do we not bleed?" *Merchant of Venice*, (Act III, scene I)

Life can turn non-living stuff into living stuff. Plants, for example, can produce more plants from quite simple chemicals. This shows that converting non-living to living stuff does not violate any laws of physics.

There is an entire generation of experiments that show many of the steps required occur spontaneously in conditions we believe would exist on the Earth before life arose. The archetypal example is the [Miller-Urey experiment.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Urey_experiment) There are many variations with a large variety of conditions and parameters. The trend is very strong. Non-living stuff such as water, oxygen, nitrogen, CO2, methane, etc., when exposed to energy such as ultraviolet, electrical discharge, etc., will produce molecules normally associated with living things. This includes such chemicals as amino acids which can spontaneously assemble into proteins.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer the question? First, I'm not asking if life came from non-life naturally.  Second, I'm not asking if life is a material process.  Third, in this question I'm not interested in specific evidence for the 'life from non life naturally' statement.  I was trying to ask whether (as used in mainstream science) that statement is an assumption or a conclusion or something else, and why.

\[I might clarify the question, but I'm not sure how, I thought it was clear enough already. :-)\]

Comment: In any meaningful interpretation of the term, Trump is a wave of electrons in my TV set, since I never see Trump except on my TV.

Comment: @yters You seem to be responding to my initial comment, but I'm not at all sure what you mean?

Comment: @MarnixKloosterReinstateMonica tongue in cheek response to BillOnne's answer.

Comment: @MarnixKloosterReinstateMonica As other have already said, it would be helpful if you were to explain what _you_ mean by "mainstream science"

Comment: @yters The notion that TV images are purely fictional is kind of interesting. However, there are millions of living eye witnesses to Trump. He has held 100s of rallies with 10s of thousands per rally. Whatever one might say about him, his ego is large enough to see from Canada with the unaided eye.

Comment: @MarnixKloosterReinstateMonica You asked what mainstream science thinks about abiogenisis through material means. It thinks what I stated. The problem for you seems to be that it does not think any of the false alternatives you tried to frame up for it.

Comment: @BillOnne Perhaps I was not clear enough in my question, but I asked not if mainstream science _believes_ it, but whether it is an a priori assumption, a conclusion based on evidence, a hypothesis, ....  (And as far as I've been able to work through the answers and comments, it seems I'm getting fairly disparate answers.)

Comment: @BillOnne the point is that "I always see X with Y" does not necessarily entail "X is Y".  Related to the "correlation does not equal causation" principle.

Comment: @yters Learning the correlation-causation shiboleth does not necessarily mean you know how to apply it. I did not say what you said. I said we never see Y without X. That is quite different.

Answer (score 4):

The answer lays somewhere between "2" and "3," in your numbered list. Or, perhaps it would be more accurate to say that depending on how you define the words, it's either one of the two, and the other is nonsense.

I'm taking a philosophical approach about what I believe the opinion of "Science" is on the question. If you ask individual biologists, physicists, organic chemists, etc. the question, you will get as many answers as people.

## Defining Science

One definition of science is say it is study of the predictive power of patterns in verifiable observations. Breaking this down:

- "Verifiable observations" are things which can be observed consistently by multiple people.
- "Patterns" are trends in those observations, such that observing one thing affects the probability of also observing another thing.
- "Predictive power" means that good science only cares about patterns that can be used to predict observations before they're made. Looking at historical data is a useful exercise for building hypotheses, but to test our hypotheses, we have to make *new observations* and see if they also fit the model.
- "The study of..." means that science looks at lots of different patterns and determines which ones have predictive power and which ones do not, eventually rejecting inaccurate models for more accurate ones.

## Defining "The Origin of Life on Earth"

I will define the origin of life on Earth as "There was some time *t1* at which no forms of life existed on Earth. After that, there is another time *t2* at which at least one form of life did exist on Earth." The origin of life is the phenomenon that took place between those two times that led to life's existence on Earth at *t2*.

## Science supports the idea that the origin of life on earth did occur

Given that we do not exist at time *t1*, we cannot observe it. We can only inspect the indirect evidence, such as the composition of rocks at various geological strata.

However, the indirect evidence shows that there was indeed an origin of life on Earth: That is to say, there is evidence in the geologic record that there was some time *t* at which there was no life on Earth. These observations have predictive power, in that we can take new samples from the geologic record and study them, and patterns based on the idea that life did not exist at certain periods will be able to predict the composition of those samples.

Science also supports that life exists today. This, too, has predictive power: we can look out the window and see plants, birds, insects, etc. depending on location.

Since science supports the ideas that life exists today and did not exist at some point in the past, science supports the idea that at least one origin of life on earth must have occurred between those two times.

Alternative explanations exist, such as the idea that we're all in a computer simulation (in which case "earth" may not exist), or that the Earth was created 6000 years ago and already had life on it at that time (in which case time *t1* did not occur), however, those explanations do not have any more power to predict future observations to justify their [added complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor), so they are not considered scientific.

## If a non-physical process has physical consequences, science observes the consequences

All science can operate only on the observable; however, unobservable processes can have observable consequences. Psychology, which studies the inner workings of the mind, can make observations by asking people questions. The processes that cause a given person to answer one way versus another are (with current technology) mostly unobservable, those answers, once given, become physical things that can be observed: ink exists circling one answer on the questionnaire instead of the other. Patterns found in what answers people circle on the questionnaire can be used to make predictions about how other, similar people, will answer similar questions in the future. Those predictions can be tested. Thus, psychology is scientific.

Similarly, if the origin of life on Earth involved an unobservable process, science does not care about the unobservable parts of it. Its consequences are physical (we observe evidence for times *t1* and *t2*). *Something* must have happened that led to primitive organic molecules existing *even if that something is that they appeared out of nowhere* (possibly as the result of an unobservable omnipotent creator causing them into existence from nothing by fiat).

All that science cares about is whether a given explanation can be used to predict future observations.

At the moment, abiogenesis is somewhat lacking in predictive power. It is "scientific" in that other (much more predictively powerful) scientific models show that abiogenesis *could have* occurred on Earth (though not necessarily that it *did*).

Those same models rebuke other explanations. For example, Physics can say with 100.00000% certainty that organic molecules do not spontaneously appear from nothing. Astronomy can say that we have not discovered any other planets that are sufficiently more likely to have had life appear *there* first and then been imported to Earth by spaceships or meteorites (there are planets that could easily have had abiogenesis events of their own, but they are unlikely to have been responsible for Earth if you consider the probabilities of those spaceships or meteorites, and the lack of evidence for spaceships or life-bearing meteorites).

## But what about the unobservable?

Abiogenesis, if it occurred, could have occurred under the direction of an unobservable creator or by random chance. Science is silent on that (though [Occam's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) is not). That is, unless we start seeing patterns in the data and that lead to predictions about when, where, and the unobservable creator will exert its influence and what the consequences will be, at which point it becomes a predictive model, and thus a real science in the same way that quantum physics or psychology is.

At the moment, I think most scientists agree that hasn't happened - even those that believe there is a creator would agree that we cannot predict the creator's actions.

Comment: +1 Welcome! Well reasoned.

Answer (score 3):

### Science Isn't a Monolith

Science doesn't think about anything; nor does it have a stance. In fact, more accurate would be to use "sciences". The sciences are technology-practices of people, called scientists, and the number and variety of sciences and scientists is staggering.

Doubtless, there are scientists out there, even biologists, who might have religious beliefs that endorse [creationism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creationism) and [intelligent design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_design), but [scientists are far less religious than the average person according to Pew](https://www.pewresearch.org/religion/2009/11/05/scientists-and-belief/). To philosophers of science, these views are not scientific. In fact, [the US court system has rejected intelligent design as a scientific theory and classified it as religious](https://www.aclu.org/other/trial-kitzmiller-v-dover). [Research on the beliefs of scientists](https://evolution-outreach.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1936-6434-6-33) have shown that biologists even more strongly than physical scientists reject religious explanations, so that leaves scientific explanations. So, many scientists are comfortable with religion, but for those who reject [supernaturalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernatural), there aren't a lot of choices but abiogenesis.

That being said, in contemporary biology, where natural selection and evolution are the linchpin of the entire discipline, it's relatively uncontroversial to accept [abiogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abiogenesis). There is no competing hypothesis that is scientific, except [panspermia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panspermia), which some might consider fringe, but is addressed by some famous biologists like Francis Crick. From WP:

> Directed panspermia would be the deliberate transport of microorganisms in space, sent to Earth to start life here, or sent from Earth to seed new planetary systems with life by introduced species of microorganisms on lifeless planets. The Nobel prize winner Francis Crick, along with Leslie Orgel proposed that life may have been purposely spread by an advanced extraterrestrial civilization.

**In short, if life didn't find it's way to our rock from outer space, of course it came from non-life here. What other non-supernatural explanations are there?**

### Philosophy and Science.

What role does philosophy play in this acceptance?

Science itself has been tremendously successful at dealing with questions that arose during the period of [natural philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_philosophy). Hence, natural philosophy is the progenitor of modern science, and a number of scientific questions that have been settled, like the rejection of [vitalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitalism), have played a key role in moving science away from its roots. The rejection of the supernatural has been key in trying to find [physicalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physicalism) explanations, and the marriage between philosophy and science under [naturalized epistemology (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epistemology-naturalized/index.html) has affected both philosophy and science.

Second, philosophy, in particular the [philosophy of science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_science), helps to address the [demarcation problem of science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demarcation_problem) and keep pseudosciences at bay. The US court system rejected intelligent design, for instances, ensuring that a state like Kansas can't teach religious doctrine as scientific theory. Since religion isn't allowed to masquerade as science, and supernatural causes are ruled out, abiogensis is really the only possibility, noting that even if panspermia is true, life had to start somewhere sometime after the Big Bang.

Third, philosophy still helps with the scientific unknowns. For instance, discussion of [emergence and supervenience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergence) are tremendously popular metaphysical views in the physical sciences. "Emergence" is the philosophical heart and soul of life coming from non-life. And it makes sense already if one considers a popular explanation of the origin of the chicken and the egg. Animals evolved that laid eggs, and eventually one branch of life became a chicken, so the chicken evolved from an ancestor and came after. But when did the ancestor become a chicken exactly? Never, a point made by the [paradox of sorites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox). [Clades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clade) are abstractions, just like our categories.

**Some argue that the category of non-living (self-replicating RNA) jumps over to living by process of categorization, invalidating notions of [natural kind (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natural-kinds/).** That "living" comes from non-living, and "conscious" comes from non-conscious is just another form of emergence. This has roots in Aristotle's notions of cause. Matter, form, agency, and purpose are intuitive notions. There are still vigorous debates over philosophical questions that have an impact on science. [Natural kinds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_kind) and [scientific instrumentalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentalism) are two examples.

### Why Many Scientists Accept Abiogenesis

Biologists of science, as shown by research, do not uniformly reject religion or religious experience, and the majority of the typical [scientist may have have positive regard for religion](https://theconversation.com/many-scientists-are-atheists-but-that-doesnt-mean-they-are-anti-religious-167677). [Philosophers and eminent scientists may have a stronger streak towards atheism (catholic.com)](https://www.catholic.com/magazine/online-edition/does-it-matter-that-many-scientists-are-atheists) and that may exert some institutional influence to reject supernatural explanations. And, among scientists who reject supernatural origins of life on earth, there is really one strong contender for explanation, abiogenesis which has empirical grounding in [Miller-Urey and contemporary research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Urey_experiment#Recent_related_studies).

Comment: I didn't realize the courts decide what is and is not science.  I thought scientists decided that.

Comment: @yters Of choose they do. When ID advocates and biologists disagree and lawsuits occur,  the courts resolve the conflict. The courts decide v what can and can't be taught as science. I'd read the decision.  It's informative.

Comment: Panspermia isn't an alternative, it just pushes the question back to how did the life that travelled to Earth originate.

Comment: @Barmar I read the question with the implicit assumption that Earth was the starting point. Herr Meister Philip cured me of that assumption. It's good to have called that out, thanks.

Comment: @JD so if the courts decide Lysenkoism is science, then it is science?

Comment: @yters In a public school, yes. If you're looking for me to say that some group of people have a privleged,  objective claim to truth, you're not going to get it from me. Philosophers of science don't necessarily agree. All anyone can do is make and vet arguments and make up their own mind

Comment: How does panspermia explain the transition from non-life to life?

Comment: @JD Do you realize that the phrases "what can and can't be taught as science" and " what is and is not science" have a different meaning? [Hint: compare and contrast the verbs.]

Comment: @phresnel Point already conceded.  See Barmar above.

Comment: @SimonCrase Exactly. See last comment above to yters about there is no objective authority to truth in vague reference to social constructionism. [Then reflect until you understand it.]

Comment: @phresnel Although technically, Earth would have undergone a transition to having life if panspermia happened

Comment: @JD " there is no objective authority to truth" Nature is the objective authority. If I perform an experiment, the measurements  are what they are.

Comment: @SimonCrase While I attend to agree w you,  measurements, both in unit and scale, are a human decision. Give me two rulers and three measurers, and I'll give you four measurements. See [theory-ladeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory-ladenness). People who agree are  merely agreeing to the same biases.

Comment: @JD so if scientists (and courts) agree intelligent design is not science, they are merely agreeing to the same biases?

Comment: @yters Sure. All philosophical positions start w presumption

Answer (score 2):

Materialism and religion don't need to be mutually exclusive. If you're a materialist and also believe in God, you can simply define God as part of the material universe. Like dark matter and dark energy, we simply don't yet know what God is actually made of and how it does what it does.

This can be seen as an alternate view of the "God of the gaps" argument for religion. Humans have always had an incomplete understanding of the universe, and religion was often used as an explanation for the things we didn't understand. Over the centuries, the scientific process has been used to formulate better explanations for many phenomena, so we've reduced the size of these gaps significantly.

Scientists don't claim to have complete explanations for everything. They mostly believe that it's conceptually *possible* to explain anything, and the scientific method is the best process to find those explanations.

Dualism is an arbitrary distinction -- if God affects the universe, what makes it "super" natural? It's just a natural process that we don't understand (yet?). If God created life from non-life, that was a natural process by definition.

A related concept is [Clarke's Third Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws):

> Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.

This figures in many science fiction stories where advanced aliens are treated as gods, as well as von Däniken's [*Chariots of the Gods*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chariots_of_the_Gods%3F), where he proposed that aliens gave technology to ancient humans, and humans revered them as gods.

Comment: I think this is the most sensible position to take in regards to the defense of a god. Superadvanced agency that simply outstrips our understanding of the universe at the moment. It's a wonder more religious people don't advocate it.

Answer (score 1):

If scientists want to be truly scientific, there is no a priori reason to accept a material origin of life.  First, we have to understand the nature of what life is.  If by its nature it cannot be material, then it cannot have a material origin.  Saying it is material because it must have a material origin is putting the cart before the horse.

The following is not meant as an argument against the idea that life is not material in origin.  It is meant as an example of the sort of analysis scientists need to do to create a scientific hypothesis, instead of assuming a certain position a priori.  It also illustrates that this sort of analysis does not of necessity conclude that life has a material origin.  The point is to show this analysis comes before drawing any conclusions about the origin of life, not visa versa as is currently the case.

To use a computer science analogy, if we analyze life and determine it is no simpler than a Type-0 language on the [Chomsky hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy), i.e. not reducible to Type-1 or simpler, then we know it cannot be produced by a finite state automata.  One life form, humans, speaks a Type-0 language, so life in general cannot be reduced to something simpler.  Physical processes, at their most complex, are merely finite state automata.  Therefore, physical processes cannot generate life, and hence life does not have a material origin.

Comment: "One life form, humans, speaks a Type-0 language, so life in general cannot be reduced to something simpler." -- please show your work

Comment: To be more clear: finite state automata cannot match parentheses. But wait! We can match parentheses with physical computers, which are (being physical) finite state automata! How is this done, and why does the same principle not apply to humans?

Comment: The point is it's at least possible in theory life is not the sort of thing that can have a physical origin.  So, that's the sort of question scientists should answer before devoting all efforts to finding the physical origin of life.

Comment: well, no. First you would have to establish that it is possible for some other origin to exist.

Comment: Yes, it is logically possible for another origin to exist.  For example, the direct cause of this message is my conscious imagining of concepts to communicate to you.  You can understand what I just said without any appeal to scientific materialism, even without appealing to the existence of a brain.  So, it is a logically coherent way to conceptualize origins.  Perhaps it is ultimately reducible to material origins, perhaps not.  But as a logical idea, the origin of this message is entirely explainable independent of any materialistic concepts, so immaterial origin is a logical possibility.

Comment: I honestly don't understand how anything you wrote there does any work towards establishing that it is possible that there is some other origin than physical for things to have.

Comment: @philosodad the point is a bit tricky, and I understand why it is hard to grasp.  We are used to interpreting everything in materialistic terms, so we assume when we have an idea that it must have a physical origin.  However, this interpretation is something we bring to the experienced reality of coming up with an idea.  Prior to learning any science as a kid, I thought of coming up with ideas as purely that: I originated an idea in my mind.  This pre-science education experience is itself a way to conceptualize origins, and still stands as a possible account of origins: as an idea in a mind.

Comment: I think there's a lot of work left to do to establish that possibility.

Answer (score -1):

A very, very strong consensus of science--we have observed every necessary step in a lab, but not the entire chain together, because the entire chain would take millennia at minimum without outside interference, and outside interference would invalidate the experiment--is "life *can* arise from non-life by purely material processes".

For that "can" statement, it is a category 3.

One key point here is the existence of things that are not-really-life and not-really-not-life. The classic example is viruses, the most famous example here is [RNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_world), but there are much simpler molecules capable of some degree of self-replication in an abiotic environment. You could call these "living molecules."

We have definitively observed living molecules arising from no-living-molecule situations in a lab.
We have definitively observed that living molecules can undergo evolution.
We have definitively observed a fossil history of life going back a long time to early animals, a variety of extant species between bacteria and viruses, and a diversity of bacteria and archaea that strongly suggest that an evolutionary pathway from bacteria to animals is at least possible.
Showing the existence of an evolutionary pathway between living molecules and cells is more difficult, and an active area of research, but I don't think anyone really believes it is impossible given the number of precursors of cells (micelles, sugars, amino acids, etc.) that can arise in abiotic environments.

Whether that is *actually what happened* is not something current science can have an opinion on beyond the statistical, and anthropic statistics is not mature enough a field to make strong claims.
For example, I would say that, because the universe is a simulation with probability=1, it is very plausible that waiting billions of years for abiogenesis was skipped over to save computational resources, and an outside-simulation power interfered.

Science is in no way tied to materialism--the only thing it is tied to is the claim that the past can be used to predict the future. This implies a vague, statistical form of cause-and-effect.
This does not preclude souls or anything, it just requires that we don't have a universe that is fundamentally unknowable and not predictable--even sometimes and approximately--because almost everything happens for no reason, and not even in a random way that can be represented with probabilities.
Most religions don't make that claim.
(Sadly, not making that claim isn't compatible with what many people want "free will" to mean--that decisions are made without influence from which the decision can be predicted.)

Comment: Just leaving a disclaimer for readers that the universe-as-simulation is pseudoscience. https://www.realclearscience.com/2021/02/15/the_simulation_hypothesis_is_pseudoscience_660321.html#!